# Command Line arguments with change directory

Tags: c#, command-line-arguments, filepath

I am trying to run command line arguments from C# console app.

Code is:

```
string[] MyArguments = { "/c", @"'C:\Program Files (x86)\salesforce.com\Data Loader\bin\process.bat'",  "\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\salesforce.com\\Data Loader\\samples\\conf\"", "accountMasterProcess" };

ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
            Process process;
            startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            startInfo.Arguments = String.Join(" ", MyArguments);


            process = Process.Start(startInfo);
            startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            process.OutputDataReceived += (sender, arg) => Console.WriteLine("received output: {0}", arg.Data);
            process.Start();
            //process.BeginOutputReadLine();
            process.WaitForExit();
            string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            string error = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();

            exitCode = process.ExitCode;

            Console.WriteLine("output>>" + (String.IsNullOrEmpty(output) ? "(none)" : output));
            Console.WriteLine("error>>" + (String.IsNullOrEmpty(error) ? "(none)" : error));
            Console.WriteLine("ExitCode: " + exitCode.ToString(), "ExecuteCommand");
            process.Close();
```

I don't see any results in cmd window. The actual arguments in cmd window is:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\salesforce.com\Data Loader\bin>process.bat "C:\Program Files (x86)\salesforce.com\Data Loader\samples\conf" accountMasterProcess
```

Please help

Comment: What's with the `/` in front of C:\?

Comment: It was a mistake. It should have been /c to consider it as a command. Thank you for pointing

Answer (score 0):

Add `/c` to your arguments. This will make `cmd.exe` reconise that you are passing a command.

Also at the start of `string[] MyArguments = { @"/C:\\Program Files (x86)\\salesforce.com\\Data Loader\\bin", "process.bat", "\"PathName"", "BeanName"};` there is a `/` before `C:` which will cause an error in cmd.

Comment: so where should I be adding /c if these are the arguments 1st argument is for changing the directory, rest are cmd arguments
{ @"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\salesforce.com\\Data Loader\\bin", "process.bat", "\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\PathName"", "BeanName"};

Comment: At the start of MyArguments `string[] MyArguments = { "/c", @"/C:\\Program Files (x86)\\salesforce.com\\Data Loader\\bin", "process.bat", "\"PathName"", "BeanName"};`

Comment: output>>(none)
error>>The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
Getting this error. Has edited the Original Post

Comment: That's odd to be getting `The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.` What is `process.bat`?

Comment: It's a batch file having
IF "%JAVA_HOME%" == "" (
    echo To run process.bat, set the JAVA_HOME environment variable to the directory where the Java Runtime Environment ^(JRE^) 
) ELSE (
    IF NOT EXIST "%JAVA_HOME%" (
        echo We couldn't find the Java Runtime Environment ^(JRE^) in directory "%JAVA_HOME%". To run process.bat, set the JAVA_HOME environment variable to the directory where the JRE is installed.
    ) ELSE (
        "%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java" -cp ..\dataloader-37.0.0-uber.jar -Dsalesforce.config.dir=%1 com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessRunner %PROCESS_OPTION%

Comment: Ahh okay, I think that the C# script is working, beacuse usually `The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.` is something to do with a batch syntatx error.